Variational formulation of the vector Laplace equation in cylindrical coordinates
I want to solve the vector Laplace equation $\nabla^2 \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{f}$ in arbitrary coordinate systems using finite-elements.
The usual way to derive the variational form necessary for the finite-element formulation is to integrate by parts the diffusion term $\nabla^2 \mathbf{v}$ muliplied by a test function $\hat{\mathbf{v}}$. In the sources that I have read, the integration by parts formula is always written in vector form as
$$
\int_\Omega(\nabla^2\mathbf{v})\cdot \hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\mathrm{d}V 
=
\int_{\partial\Omega}(\nabla\mathbf{v})\mathbf{n}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\mathrm{d}S 
- 
\int_{\Omega}\nabla\mathbf{v}:\nabla\hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\mathrm{d}V
$$
where $\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B}=A_{ij}B_{ij}$, $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=a_ib_i$ and $\mathbf{n}$ is the outward normal to the domain boundary $\partial\Omega$. Where things get tricky is that this formula seems correct only in Cartesian coordinates. In cylindrical coordinates, for example, I obtained by integrating "by hand" the following formula:
$$
\int_{\Omega}\big(\nabla^2\mathbf{v}\big)\cdot\hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\mathrm{d} V 
= \int_{\partial\Omega} (\nabla \mathbf{v})\mathbf{n} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\mathrm{d} S - \int_{\Omega} \nabla \mathbf{v} : \nabla \hat{\mathbf{v}}\,\mathrm{d} V \; \cdots \\
- \int_{\Omega} \left\{
        \left( \frac{v_r}{r} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial \theta} \right)\frac{\hat{v_r}}{r}
      + \left( \frac{v_{\theta}}{r} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta} \right)\frac{\hat{v_\theta}}{r}
    \right\}\mathrm{d} V
$$
where the entries of the gradient of a vector, organised here in matrix form, are here (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensors_in_curvilinear_coordinates)
$$
\nabla\mathbf{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial r}   & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta}   & \frac{\partial v_r}{\partial z}  \\
\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial r}  & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial \theta} & \frac{v_\theta}{z} \\
\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial r}   & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v_z}{\partial \theta}  & \frac{\partial v_z}{\partial z}   
\end{bmatrix},
$$
while for the Laplacian of a scalar and a vector we have respectively:
$$
\nabla^2v = \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial r^2}+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial z^2},
\quad
\nabla^2\mathbf{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla^2 v_r    - \frac{v_r }{r^2}    - \frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial \theta}\\
\nabla^2 v_\theta - \frac{v_\theta}{r^2} - \frac{2}{r^2}\frac{\partial v_r}{\partial \theta}  \\[1ex]
\nabla^2 v_z
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So that's fine for cylindrical coordinates, but what about the general case? So my question is: is there a reference to a general formula for integration by parts, which applies in any coordinate system? (even curvilinear, non-orthogonal).
Thanks.

Not exactly an answer to your question, but here is one useful paper: https://www.math.purdue.edu/~shen7/pub/Polar.pdf

Well, there is a way using differential forms, see e. g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/229004/317987 The 'trick' is to use coordinate-less approach, which is elegant for the formulation and organizes your computations systematically. But amount of work needed for the task will remain the same.
